# While loop exits with non-matching username / password

Tags: java, authentication, while-loop, do-while

So this is only a tiny bit of my program but essentially what I'm trying to do is make a basic authentication while loop. I'm not sure if I should use a while loop or something else.
All I want the program to do is stop looping if the username and  password match the "account".
I'm not sure if this question is clear but it's the best I can do. If you need any clarification, let me know.

Edit: If I type in the wrong username or password, it doesn't loop again. That's my problem.

This is the part where I'm having a problem:

```
User user2 = new User();
        userList.add(user2);
        String userLogin = "estebangong23";
        String userPass = "twitterisfun";
        String existingUserName = " ";
        String existingPassWord = " ";

        user2.setUserName("estebangong23");
        user2.setEmailAddress("esteban.gong@yahoo.com");
        user2.setPassWord("twitterisfun");

        System.out.println("Please sign in here.");

        while (!existingUserName.equals("estebangong23") && existingPassWord.equals("twitterisfun")) {

            System.out.println("Username: ");
            existingUserName = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
            existingPassWord = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            //System.out.println("Log In unsuccessful. Incorrect username or password.");
        }
```

Below is most of my program:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    // make it so u can log in to an existing account
    // make it double check the password and email

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    List<String> matchesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String date = "03/21/2019";
    String tweet = " ";

    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("|                               Twitter                                 |");
    System.out.println("| Sign Up                                                        Log in |");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    System.out.println("Would you like to Log In or Sign Up?");
    String responseString = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();


    if (responseString.equals("signup") ) {

        User user1 = new User(); //this creates the first user

        System.out.println("Alright, lets get started by setting up your profile!");

        System.out.println("Please enter a username.");
        user1.setUserName(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Please enter your email address.");
        user1.setEmailAddress(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Please enter a password.");
        user1.setPassWord(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Alright we got your account all setup. Just take a moment to review everthing. Don't worry you can change this stuff later if you want!");
        user1.printUserProfile();

        userList.add(user1);

        System.out.println("Your account is all setup, go ahead and try posting something for the first time!");


        } else { //end signup if

        User user2 = new User();
        userList.add(user2);
        String userLogin = "estebangong23";
        String userPass = "twitterisfun";
        String existingUserName = " ";
        String existingPassWord = " ";

        user2.setUserName("estebangong23");
        user2.setEmailAddress("esteban.gong@yahoo.com");
        user2.setPassWord("twitterisfun");

        System.out.println("Please sign in here.");

        while (!existingUserName.equals("estebangong23") && existingPassWord.equals("twitterisfun")) {

            System.out.println("Username: ");
            existingUserName = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
            existingPassWord = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            //System.out.println("Log In unsuccessful. Incorrect username or password.");
        } 

        } //end else

    //main program
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Let's post something! Show the world what your thinking about righ now!");
    System.out.println("If you want to stop entering tweets at any time, please enter '**'. ");

    System.out.println(" ");

    while (!tweet.equals("**")) {

        System.out.println("Enter your tweet here: ");
        tweet = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        String[] tweetArray = tweet.split(" ");

        System.out.println("");




    } //end tweet while loop


    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    } //end main

    } //end main class

    class User {
    // this class sets up the users profile when they are signing up
private String userName;
private String emailAddress;
private String passWord;
public List<Tweet> tweetList = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

//Username, Age, Email Address, Tweets[ ]
//Methods
//Setters and getters, Create tweet
public User () {

}

public String getUserName() {return this.userName;}
public void setUserName(String userName) {this.userName = userName;}

public String getEmailAddress() {return this.emailAddress;}
public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {this.emailAddress = emailAddress;}

public String getPassWord() {return this.passWord;}
public void setPassWord(String passWord) {this.passWord = passWord;}

public void printUserProfile() {
    System.out.println("Username: " + this.userName);
    System.out.println("Email Address: " + this.emailAddress);
    System.out.println("Password (remember not to share this to anyone) " + this.passWord);
}
```

}

Comment: Well, is it working or not? I don't see a problem statement.

Comment: Looks like the code is working but you don't have the code for success scenario which is just after the loop.

Comment: That should be `||` not `&&` in the `while` condition. (And I hope that's not your real password...)

Comment: Its not working because I do have code after. But if I type in the wrong credentials it still goes on.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], otherwise we're all in the dark on what part it is that's not working. As it is now, your incomplete code simply doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ok I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply answer your question,

```
while (! (existingUserName.equals(userLogin) && existingPassWord.equals(userPass)) ) { // if users doesn't exist
...

}
```

However, you need to rethink your code for authentication. I'm guessing you've just begun. Start by putting them in a table and access them using PreparedStatement.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a PreparedStatement but I will do some research. Thanks

Comment: If the suggestion works for you, you need to mark it (click on the tick mark). That way, others wouldn't look through the question again and will go on to help other unanswered questions.

Comment: It should be `!existingPassWord.equals(...)`.